# Why sometimes when running the game the text subtitles in the game is in color black?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The colors settings the same in the Hierarchy as before running the game and yet sometimes when running the game in the game the text is in black. Most of the times it's in the colors of the Hierarchy settings.

[image: Text in black]

After twice I tried again in the it's in the original color it should be from the Hierarchy :

[image: Text in original color]

Could be a problem in the editor only ? Or maybe somewhere in my scripts I'm doing something wrong ? It's strange that sometimes it's in black and sometimes in the color it should be.